# Running CppCheck from PowerShell & redirecting output

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, redirection

I want to run CppCheck from PowerShell (on Windows10).
Here's the command that works on MSDOS Command Shell:
`"C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe" --project=./Static_Analysis_Support/utfa_static_analysis.cppcheck > nul: 2> cppcheck_errors.txt`

When run on PowerShell, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\sandboxes\git\utfa> "C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe" --project=./Static_Analysis_Support/utfa_static_analysis.cppcheck > nul: 2> cppcheck_errors.txt
At line:1 char:44
+ ... heck.exe" --project=./Static_Analysis_Support/utfa_static_analysis.cp ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'project=./Static_Analysis_Support/utfa_static_analysis.cppcheck' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ "C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe" --project=./Static_Analysis_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The '--' operator works only on variables or on properties.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I want to run CppCheck and redirect the "action verbage" to nul device and redirect the XML error output to a file.

I'm very new to PowerShell and only using it with a a GitLab runner on a server.

Comment: do a search on `powershell run exe with args` for the why of what went wrong - and how to fix it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

See
• PowerShell: Running Executables

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

`5. The Call Operator &`

and

`7. Start-Process  (start/saps)`